# Why did Steppenwolf's spikes disappear when Darkseid appeared?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

The spikes on Steppenwolf's armour disappeared when Darkseid appeared before him:

[image: Steppenwolf without spiked armor]

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a symbolic show of deference, which reflects his humility before and fealty to Darkseid, similar to those shown by our knights.

[image: a medieval knight kneeling before royalty in an act of deference]

In an interview with [Yahoo Sports](https://sports.yahoo.com/justice-league-snyder-cut-secrets-vfx-darkseid-steppenwolf-knightmare-behind-the-scenes-181934458.html?guccounter=1), director Zack Snyder said,

> "He's a legit space knight."

and WETA Digital Visual Effect Supervisor Anders Langlands added,

> "Zack had the idea that his armor would react to his mood and be part of his performance, as if it was some kind of alien technology that’s symbiotic with him."

So the armor is reflecting Steppenwolf's deference to Darkseid.

Comment: Some very good finds. You might want to consider a name-change though...

Comment: Even not having seen this cut, this would have been my interpretation as well. A classical sign of defedence. Taking off his crown.